# Node.js DNS response delayed

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, dns, callback

I'm just trying to concatenate an array containing domains that are the result of a DNS resolution.

This is my code :

```
        var ipList = [];
        for(var j=0; j < addressList.length; j++) {
            dns.resolve(addressList[j], function(error, ipRange) {
                if(error !== null) {
                    console.log('The DNS request failed.');
                }
                console.log('--1--');
                console.log(ipRange);
                console.log('--2--');
                ipList.concat(ipRange);
            });
        }

        console.log(ipList);
```

The result I'm getting is this :

```
[]
--1--
[ '173.194.35.144',
  '173.194.35.145',
  '173.194.35.146',
  '173.194.35.147',
  '173.194.35.148' ]
--2--
```

It looks like the DNS resolution response arrives after the `concat()`, like it was delayed.
Which means that ipList is an empty array.

Can anyone help me on this ?
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this where you keep track of the number of DNS queries still outstanding so that you can tell when the full set is available:

```
var ipList = [], count = addressList.length;
for(var j=0; j < addressList.length; j++) {
    dns.resolve(addressList[j], function(error, ipRange) {
        if(error !== null) {
            console.log('The DNS request failed.');
        } else {
            ipList.push(ipRange);
        }
        if (--count === 0) {
            // All DNS queries are complete.
            console.log(ipList);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Your `ipList.concat` call should be `ipList.push` instead.  I updated my post.

Comment: Oh yeah totally missed that. Everything works fine now. Thank you for your quick answer !

Answer (score 4):

resolve is async, so it's not done when you do the final print.  Use synchronous DNS (can't find this for node.js immediately), or arrange your callbacks properly.

Comment: Hum damned, I thought it would be something like this. Sadly I have no idea on how to solve it ...

Comment: @AwakeZoldiek, you could try recursion (passing in a callback which calls `console.log(ipList);` if addressList will never be long.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. Could you give an example ?

Comment: @AwakeZoldiek True understanding of JavaScript's single thread nature and `process.nextTick` is required http://howtonode.org/understanding-process-next-tick

Comment: @AwakeZoldiek https://github.com/caolan/async async module is using `process.nextTick` as well